# Accusative pronoun in interrogative sentence with "wert sein"?

Tags: grammatical-case

If the adjective **wert** takes the accusative case, then should I consider the pronoun **was** as an accusative pronoun in the following interrogative sentence?

> **Was** ist es **wert**?

Answer (score 4):

In this context with *sein* *[wert](https://dwds.de/wb/wert)* takes the accusative case, therefore *[was](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/was:Pron:Relative:Interrog:N)* is accusative. This is easy to see after you had answered the question:

> Es ist keinen Cent wert.

Sometimes you also may still hear or read it with genitive case:

> Er ist des Vertrauens wert. (*Question:* Wessen ist er wert?)

Comment: In case like Wassen, Is it correct or work in german to have question word in one case and corresponding answer word in different case?

Comment: @tgth: usually it is expected to take the same case, which makes it an easy to use tool to check on grammatical cases. Because that is so I gave you the corresponding question to the genitive case (which would not work well but would still be understood with accusative)